# PHP Simple HTML DOM - Get the 2nd and 3rd paragraph from the DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM Library to get the 2nd paragraph in the DOM of a website, but what I'd like to do is get the 2nd and the 3rd.

This gets me the 2nd `<p>` in the DOM:

```
$dates->find('.content .left div.linkDetail p', 2)->plaintext;
```

How can I extend this to get the 2nd and the 3rd?

Comment: Concatenate it to the one that returns the 3rd? `$dates->find('.content .left div.linkDetail p', 3)->plaintext;`

Comment: Was hoping Simple HTML DOM had some 'magic' method but that works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$pArray = array_slice( $dates->find('.content .left div.linkDetail p'),2,2 );
```